# MySQL WeekOfYear() with Timezone?

Tags: php, mysql

My webserver is in France & my database has Europe Paris timezone set...
My website is actually meant to be used by people living in Portugal where they got -1H less than I have in France...

I'm using this query to **get likes of the week**. The problem is when it's the new week in France assuming Monday 00h30 for example, it should still give me results of last week cause in Portugal it's still Sunday 23h30....

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) as likes, user 
 FROM likes_week 
 WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(data_e) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()) 
 GROUP BY user ORDER BY likes"
```

So my question is, is there any way to do what I want with a SQL query or I can only do that in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do something like this

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) as likes, user 
 FROM likes_week WHERE date_column 
 BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, -1, GETDATE()) 
 AND DATEADD(week,-1,GETDATE()) 
 GROUP BY user ORDER BY likes"
```

Remember I have assumed that name of your date column is 'date_column'
And I am taking dates between 1hr ago and 1 week ago.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Praem happy to help !

Answer (score 0):

That's depend on how you store your dates & times.

If that is TIMESTAMP - it's just plain UTC in the form of Unix Time. It is automatically converted into server's timezone, specified or default.

If it is DATETIME - timezone supposed to be in.

Then it depends on how you write it into DB. If server is in France, and the timezone set properly, and MySQL is using default settings - all the DATETIME values should be in THAT timezone, the French one.